# Codeigniter 3.1.9 - CI_Session is filling up my database on every refresh

Tags: database, codeigniter, session, phpmyadmin, session-variables

I have been getting back into `Codeigniter` as support was picked up by [BCIT](http://www.bcit.ca/). I have a problem with `ci_sessions` and the database driver which is regenerating the encrypted session ID and storing new data in my database on every page refresh. I'm so frustrated right now! I have both secure file storage and database for both common drivers. I want to use both or either but the effect on my application is the same whether I am using a database or files. The `ci_session` keeps refreshing and it is not ideal for logins, registration or any account type. Please help me see what I am doing wrong? Much appreciation granted in advance.

Config:

```
    $config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
    $config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
    $config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
    $config['sess_save_path'] = 'users';
    $config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
    $config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
    $config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Controllers:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * User Management class created by CodexWorld
 */
class Limousers extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('user');
    }

    /*
     * User account information
     */
    public function account(){
        print_r($_SESSION);
        $data = array();
        print_r($this->session->userdata());
        if($this->session->userdata('isUserLoggedIn')){
            $data['user'] = $this->user->getRows(array('id'=>$this->session->userdata('userId')));
            //load the view
            $this->load->view('limousers/account', $data);
        }else{

            redirect('limousers/login');
            exit;
        }
    }

    /*
     * User login
     */
    public function login(){
        print_r($_SESSION);
        if($this->session->userdata('isUserLoggedIn'))
        {
            print_r($this->session->userdata);

            redirect('limousers/account');
            exit;
        }
        $data = array();
        if($this->session->userdata('success_msg')){
            $data['success_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('success_msg');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('success_msg');
        }
        if($this->session->userdata('error_msg')){
            $data['error_msg'] = $this->session->userdata('error_msg');
            $this->session->unset_userdata('error_msg');
        }
        if($this->input->post('loginSubmit')){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() == true) {
                $con['returnType'] = 'single';
                $con['conditions'] = array(
                    'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                    'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                    'status' => '1'
                );
                $checkLogin = $this->user->getRows($con);
                if($checkLogin){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('name',$con['conditions']['email']);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('isUserLoggedIn',TRUE);
                    $this->session->set_userdata('userId',$checkLogin['id']);
                    redirect('limousers/account');
                    exit;
                }else{
                    $data['error_msg'] = 'Wrong email or password, please try again.';
                }
            }
        }
        //load the view
        $this->load->view('limousers/login', $data);
    }

    /*
     * User registration
     */
    public function registration(){
        print_r($_SESSION);
        $data = array();
        $userData = array();
        if($this->input->post('regisSubmit')){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|valid_email|callback_email_check');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('conf_password', 'confirm password', 'required|matches[password]');

            $userData = array(
                'name' => strip_tags($this->input->post('name')),
                'email' => strip_tags($this->input->post('email')),
                'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'gender' => $this->input->post('gender'),
                'phone' => strip_tags($this->input->post('phone'))
            );

            if($this->form_validation->run() == true){
                $insert = $this->user->insert($userData);
                if($insert){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('success_msg', 'Your registration was successfully. Please login to your account.');
                    redirect('limousers/login');
                    exit;
                }else{
                    $data['error_msg'] = 'Some problems occured, please try again.';
                }
            }
        }
        $data['user'] = $userData;
        //load the view
        $this->load->view('limousers/registration', $data);
    }

    /*
     * User logout
     */
    public function logout(){
        $this->session->unset_userdata('isUserLoggedIn');
        $this->session->unset_userdata('userId');
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        redirect('limousers/login');
        exit;
    }

    /*
     * Existing email check during validation
     */
    public function email_check($str){
        $con['returnType'] = 'count';
        $con['conditions'] = array('email'=>$str);
        $checkEmail = $this->user->getRows($con);
        if($checkEmail > 0){
            $this->form_validation->set_message('email_check', 'The given email already exists.');
            return FALSE;
        } else {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
}
```

Models:

```
 <?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access 
    allowed');
    class User extends CI_Model{
    function __construct() {
        $this->userTbl = 'users';
    }
    /*
     * get rows from the users table
     */
    function getRows($params = array()){
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($this->userTbl);

        //fetch data by conditions
        if(array_key_exists("conditions",$params)){
            foreach ($params['conditions'] as $key => $value) {
                $this->db->where($key,$value);
            }
        }

        if(array_key_exists("id",$params)){
            $this->db->where('id',$params['id']);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            $result = $query->row_array();
        }else{
            //set start and limit
            if(array_key_exists("start",$params) && 
    array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
                $this->db->limit($params['limit'],$params['start']);
            }elseif(!array_key_exists("start",$params) && 
    array_key_exists("limit",$params)){
                $this->db->limit($params['limit']);
            }
            $query = $this->db->get();
            if(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && 
    $params['returnType'] == 'count'){
                $result = $query->num_rows();
            }elseif(array_key_exists("returnType",$params) && 
    $params['returnType'] == 'single'){
    $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query- >row_array():FALSE;
    }else{
    $result = ($query->num_rows() > 0)?$query->result_array():FALSE;
            }
        }

        //return fetched data
        return $result;
     }

     /*
      * Insert user information
      */
     public function insert($data = array()) {
        //add created and modified data if not included
        if(!array_key_exists("created", $data)){
            $data['created'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }
        if(!array_key_exists("modified", $data)){
            $data['modified'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        }

        //insert user data to users table
        $insert = $this->db->insert($this->userTbl, $data);

        //return the status
        if($insert){
            return $this->db->insert_id();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
      }

    }
```

Comment: What code you have tried so far?

Comment: I have autoloaded library session set the driver to either file and database on different occasions. I am updating session data manually once in registration, once on log in and once on logout. That's I want to happen. As far as encrypting the session ID and storing the session data, that is handled by the database driver. I am also using php's redirect() function. Should I use $this->load->view() or Header()? Or maybe it's because I am autoloading the library when I should be loading it once and/or checking to see if it's already loaded.

Comment: Im using apache2 php7 and this should be pretty straight forward. I am not sure why it wants to regenerate the session on every refresh.

Comment: Also I am not sending any cookies to the client. I feel like that is safest. Even if I do the result is the same. The session regenerates.

Comment: Share your code

Comment: Please show all the session and cookie `$config` settings you are using.

Comment: That the same thing happens for both the database and file drivers makes me think it is probably something in your code. Perhpas you should share your log in and log out code.

Comment: Thanks guys. I updated my question.

Comment: wait what about MATCH IP????? one sec.

Comment: that didnt work

Comment: i am starting clean and creating a separate helper to handle session create, update and delete. I didn't realize that the data column was serialized.